# ajax variable not usable in php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, variables

I have written an AJAX script that needs to send out some variables to a PHP script and then report back a little script to connect with a server. However I can seem to use the store variables I have passed on from my AJAX script

```
<script>
function executeSsh() {
    var username = "<?php echo $connect_d["username"] ?>";
    var password = "<?php echo $connect_d["password"] ?>";
    var ip       = "<?php echo $connect_d["dedicatedip"] ?>";

    $.ajax({
        url: "functions.php",
        dataType: 'text',
        type: "post",            
        data: { username: username, password: password, ip: ip },
        success: function(data) {
                $('#sshcall').html( data );
            },
        error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
            }
    });

    $('.blinstbtn').fadeToggle(1000);
}
</script>
```

So now you can see the three variables who are passed to PHP as they should and stored as they should in separate variables. However at this point I can't use them any longer and I get a connection error.

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$ip       = $_POST['ip'];

echo $username. "<br><br>". $password;

$ssh = new Net_SSH2($ip);
if (!$ssh->login($username, $password)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

$ssh->read('/.*@.*[$|#]/', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX);
$ssh->write("uptime\n");
$ssh->setTimeout(10);
$output = $ssh->read('/.*@.*[$|#]|.*[P|p]assword.*/', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX);

echo "<pre>". $output . "</pre>";
?>
```

So when I echo out each variable it should the correct value, but when I try to used then further down the script I keep getting the message that login didn't work. I know the script to connect to the server is working as I tested it with just the raw info.

Any idea what I am missing here and how I can solve it. Is there also a way to encrypt the data string that is being send by AJAX so now one can pickup the values with something like Firebug?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Since you're trying to return html I would use the "html" datatype instead of text, just to start off with.. Can you error_log($_POST['username']); and see if it's returning the expected value in your error log? You can even try loggin the entire post object to see if it's coming through error_log(print_r($_POST, true));

Comment: well as said the variables are getting passed on and stored into the variable. When i use echo and then the i get the right response.

But after that i can't use it too fill in the info i need for some reason. Its like there is not enough time to pass on the variables to the lower script or something.

Comment: Please check the error log and put any pertinent lines of that above. Also might be worth checking the client side errors too (if any).

Comment: You have to use in ajax not url: "templates/cloudblok/php/functions.php". Value 'url' will be begin from "http://" or  "https".

Comment: One thing, in the `var username`, etc, you will need to do `var username = '<?php echo $connect_d["username"] ?>';` (notice the single and then double quotes). Having the double quotes within double quotes won't work.

Comment: all good stuff that i am going to check and see if this will work. if any one has anything else please let me know.

As i am outputting a script should the type not be script? I can't really find when you would use script. Can any one explain.

Comment: I have tried everything, there are no errors or anything. I have adjusted everything and it seems that the $password = $_POST['password']; is not storing the value correctly or the rest of the script just doesn't want to take it or because it is being passed it is not being executed any more which is odd because it works in echo. When i store the login just a plan text and then use the variables it is working. So i am not sure why it is doing this.

Answer (score -1):

I just figured it out. I need to use trim (http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) in front of $post to make this work. There might have been white spaces added when i used post. Not sure how that is possible. but it is what worked for me.

Thanks for all the input. If any one would like to tell me why there are white spaces added when using post, that would be great.

Thanks